# Viable to dual boot Windows alongside OS X for games?

Tags: windows, macos, ssd

I need some advice. I'm currently running OS X Mountain Lion on my computer on an old HDD. Now there's some games I want to play on Windows, and I'm thinking of getting a big SSD and dual booting OS X ML and Windows 8. Is this possible to even do on a single drive? How long time can I expect to switch OSes on a modern SSD? I would probably prefer to have a switch time of less than, say 20 seconds. Is this realistic to pursue with an SSD?

Comment: Your asking advice, you should change your post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no problem dual booting Windows & Os X from an SSD. You must remember, though, that Bootcamp can not install/run Windows on an external drive. Windows **must** be installed on an internal drive.

Here's a [video comparing Win8/OsX boot times from SSD](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tl7MCWFof-U).